# A parameter of ui-router in controller and resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I have configured the following ui-router.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('global.editor', {
            url: '/posts/editor/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
            controller: 'EditorCtrl',
            resolve: {
                post: ['$stateParams', 'codeService', function ($stateParams, codeService) {
                    return codeService.getPost($stateParams.id)
                }]
            }
        }
        .state('global.new', {
            url: '/new',
            templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
            controller: 'EditorCtrl'
        })
        .state('global.newTRUE', {
            url: '/newTRUE',
            templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
            controller: 'EditorCtrl'
        })           
        .state('global.editor.panels', {
            controller: 'PanelsCtrl',
            params: { layout: 'horizontal' },
            templateUrl: function (params) { return "/htmls/" + params.layout + '.html' }
        }
}])

app.controller('EditorCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.layout = "horizontal";
    $scope.$watch('layout', function () {
        $state.go('global.editor.panels', { layout: $scope.layout });
    });
}]);
```

As a result, https://localhost:3000/#/new in a browser leads to (the state `global.editor`, then to) the state `global.editor.panels`.

Now, I want to add a parameter `connected`:

1. I don't want it to be shown in the url
2. https://localhost:3000/#/new in a browser makes `connected` to be `false`, and https://localhost:3000/#/newTRUE in a browser makes `connected` to be `true`
3. `connected` can be past into the controller `EditorCtrl` and `PanelsCtrl`
4. `connected` can be available in the `resolve` of `global.editor`; ideally, we could resolve different objects according to the value of `connected`.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: From your post I'm not sure whether you tried it or not, but why not add `resolve` for both `global.new` and `global.newTRUE` states. Something like `resolve: { connected: true/false }` in those states. Based on this, it should be available in EditorCtrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely use the [**`params`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls) of UI-Router states' config to not show it in URL and achieve all mentioned points.

Also, as per **#2**, you need `connected` to be `false` for `/new` and `true` for `/newTRUE`. We can do so by passing `true` or `false` as default value for those states. Something like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('global.editor', {
        url: '/posts/editor/{id}',
        templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
        params: { connected: null },
        controller: 'EditorCtrl',
        resolve: {
            post: ['$stateParams', 'codeService', function ($stateParams, codeService) {
                return codeService.getPost($stateParams.id)
            }]
        }
    }
    .state('global.new', {
        url: '/new',
        templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
        params: { connected: false }, // default false for /new
        controller: 'EditorCtrl'
    })
    .state('global.newTRUE', {
        url: '/newTRUE',
        templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
        params: { connected: true }, // default true for /newTRUE
        controller: 'EditorCtrl'
    })           
    .state('global.editor.panels', {
        controller: 'PanelsCtrl',
        params: { layout: 'horizontal', connected: null },
        templateUrl: function (params) { return "/htmls/" + params.layout + '.html' }
    }
```

For **#3**, In order to access `connected` in your controllers (`EditorCtrl` and `PanelsCtrl`) you can inject `$stateParams` to controller and use `$stateParams.connected` to get it.

For **#4**, (*This is more or less similar to achieveing **#3***)

Just like you get `$stateParams.id`, you can have `$stateParams.connected` as well, which you can use to resolve different objects according to the value of `connected`. Something like this:

```
.state('global.editor', {
    url: '/posts/editor/{id}',
    templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
    params: { connected: null },
    controller: 'EditorCtrl',
    resolve: {
        post: ['$stateParams', 'codeService', function ($stateParams, codeService) {
            return $stateParams.connected ? 
                codeService.getPost($stateParams.id) :
                codeService.getSomethingElse($stateParams.id) 
        }]
    }
}
```

But, for that to work, make sure that you are passing `connected` as params when you visit `global.editor` state (using [`$state.go`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) or [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref))

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can add resolve for new and newTRUE:

```
 .state('global.new', {
     url: '/new',
     templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
     resolve: {
         isConnected: function() {
             return false;
         }
     },
     controller: 'EditorCtrl'
 })
 .state('global.newTRUE', {
     url: '/newTRUE',
     templateUrl: '/htmls/editor.html',
     resolve: {
         isConnected: function() {
             return true;
         }
     },
     controller: 'EditorCtrl'
 })
```

And in EditorCtrl (or PanelsCtrl) you can use it like:

```
app.controller('EditorCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'isConnected', function($scope, $state, isConnected) {
    console.log("connected : " + isConnected); // you can save this value in Service and use it later.
    ...
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use classic approach - in resolve

Or you can use hidden parameters from angular ui router. 
Define `params : {isConnected' : null}` in your parent `global` state.
In:

- global.newTRUE - set value in $state config
- global.new - set value in $state config
- global.editor.panels - set parameters in `transition/go` or `ui-sref`

definition is like this:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('global.newTRUE', {
        url : '/:newTRUE',
        params : {
          'isConnected' : false
        }
   });
}
```

and in controller you get in from `$stateParams`.
Problem with this approach is hidden parameters are loses in refresh page, except if is set default value